# How we can find an admissible change of variables that goes from (0,2) to $(-\infty,0)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, curves, change-of-variable

I find a text on the web about curves and it ask for an admissible change of variables that goes from (0,2) to (-$\infty$, 0), I think about log(-x) or some function like that, but I really don't get it, any hints on this one?

Comment: Would $y=\ln x-\ln 2$ work?

Comment: $\frac12-\frac1x$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan\left[\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{x}{2} - 1\right)\right].$$